# Enumerating XML Namespaces and Adding XML Namespaces

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm having a horrible time finding any information to help me figure out how to add XML Namespaces from one XML document to another. I have tried working with the System.XML.XmlNamespaceManager class to no avail. As an example, lets say that I have an XML document like this:

```
<mso:customUI xmlns:x2="DMOLAddin" xmlns:x1="MimecastServicesForOutlook.AddinModule" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<mso:ribbon>
foo
</mso:customUI>
```

And I have another XML document like this:

```
<mso:customUI xmlns:x3="crmaddin.RibbonAddin" xmlns:x2="DMOLAddin" xmlns:x1="MimecastServicesForOutlook.AddinModule" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<mso:ribbon>
Bar
</mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

How would I go about enumerating the namespaces in document one and add only the ones to document two that don't already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```bsh
[xml]$xml1 = @"
<mso:customUI xmlns:x2="DMOLAddin" xmlns:x1="MimecastServicesForOutlook.AddinModule" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<mso:ribbon>
foo
</mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
"@

[xml]$xml2 = @"
<mso:customUI xmlns:x3="crmaddin.RibbonAddin" xmlns:x2="DMOLAddin" xmlns:x1="MimecastServicesForOutlook.AddinModule" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<mso:ribbon>
Bar
</mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
"@

$ns1 =  $xml1.customUI.Attributes |
        Where-Object { $_.Prefix -eq 'xmlns' }
$ns2 =  $xml2.customUI.Attributes |
        Where-Object { $_.Prefix -eq 'xmlns' } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.LocalName }

$ns1 | Where-Object {
    $ns2 -notcontains $_.LocalName
} | ForEach-Object {
    $xml2.customUI.SetAttribute($_.Name, $_.Value)
}
```